# How to create same ssh key pair on different systesm at different times

Tags: cryptography, ssh, key

Was going through the SSH key pair generation and did tried with the few systems i have. refer to the below command and the thumbprint value post key pair generation.

```
$ ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa): ./temp
./temp already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in ./temp.
Your public key has been saved in ./temp.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:E5wTTU48K+MPU5TUhBB62L/tYGfpWrb4KysfVrPajhs user@localhost
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|        +B+=.    |
|       = =B .    |
|      o B..o     |
|       .o+o      |
|       .S+. o    |
|        +. + +   |
|         +E O    |
|        .oo/ .   |
|         oOBO.   |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Is it possible to generate same ssh key pair on multiple systems?

If yes how can same key pairs can be generated.?

what are other parameters ssh-keygen uses which are specific to that system.?

Comment: (OpenSSH) ssh-keygen doesn't have _any_ parameters specific to the system it runs on. Mostly it uses random data that is different on every _invocation_, by design. It  has some parameters that depend on the OpenSSH _version_, and while different systems sometimes have different versions of OpenSSH, no system has a version unique to itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to generate same ssh key pair on multiple systems?

No. That would not be secure. The key pair should be unique, and are made in a fashion that attempts to ensure this. As no communication happens during generation, no hard guarantee can be made, but they can be big enough that the chance of a collission is essentially zero.

To have the same keys multiple places, copy them. They are plain text files, which can be copied. But a better alternative would probably be to generate one key pair per system, and all desired public keys to the hosts you connect to. That way, you can revoke a single key pair if you loose control of it's private key.

Comment: Agree it will not be secure. how can i generate one such (Same ssh-key pair from multiple machines) for my test purpose.? can this be realized by any options of ssh-keygen utility.?

Comment: One more to add, am using the key pair for signing the data and not for system access over SSH.

Comment: manju: there is no way to do this with OpenSSH; that project is zealous (some would say fanatic) about security and regularly rejects any feature that is or too easily could be insecure, even if useful (which your feature isn't) -- e.g. their semi-removal a few years ago of DSS-aka-DSA.